# LCD connector identification

Tags: identification, connector, lcd

I have a little PCB which converts a 42 pin LCD connector from a laptop MB to 12 pins and 22 pins for the LCD. I need to replace the 42 pin connector. How do I identify it precisely, or identify what kind of connectors should work here too?

From imprecise measures of the PCB pins, I got 20 mm for 40 pins. The connector takes the cable parallel to the PCB. There's no holding system for the cable other than the tightness. The connector seems to be (from imprecise measures): 25.18 mm or 24.52 mm or 26.09 mm large, 1.4-0.78 mm tall and 2.5-3.23 mm long. The MB pins seems to have 40 identical pins, 2 lager pins on the ends and 2 slots to solder the connector ends.

[Pictures](https://mega.nz/folder/YJpziAyL#puqS3KV92UwwXuRC3yJ7SA)

For an Asus ZenBook UX480FD-BE015T

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any pictures?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=42+pin+LCD+connector&sxsrf=AOaemvKFGot9VHrwBHO3rE4ZivBmbpztnA:1633986456638&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjGycLyocPzAhXMm2oFHTIPDUcQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1760&bih=867&dpr=1.09

Comment: Please include the images directly in your post (as at least as links to the individual images) rather than linking to an archive.

Answer (score 1):

That is an "LVDS" (Low-voltage differential signalling) connector. https://uk.rs-online.com/web/c/connectors/pcb-connectors-wire-housings/lvds-connectors/. The pitch is 0.5 mm.

I used my [connector identification utility](http://connectorbook.com/identification.html?st=1&nm=by_names&bm=by_compon&c=interior_rect_conn&u=wire_to_board_conn&o=flat_ra_w2b_conn&f=flat_lvds_w2b_conn&fl=00000000000000000000000000000000-500-%7C0.5%7C%7C%7C%7C) to identify it. It could be:

- MANUF. - SERIES
- JAE - FI-R https://www.jae.com/en/connectors/series/detail/id=64290&type_code=T1040
- JAE - HD https://www.jae.com/en/connectors/series/detail/product/id=64375&type_code=T1040